# When an entry is casted does the entry-object changes permanently in a list

Tags: python, casting

I this nested list in which the inner list has two items, a name and a float value. I got curious about casting and used two different approaches to  produce the list as follows.

Method 1:

```
n = int(input())
lis = [[input() for i in range(2)] for y in range(n)]
for k, v in lis:
    v = float(v)
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[['a', '-25.001'], ['b', '-25.0001'], ['c', '-25.000'], ['d', '-25.0']]
```

Method 2:

```
n = int(input())
lis=[]
for i in range(n):
    lis.append([input(),float(input())])
print(lis)
```

Output:

```
[['a', -25.001], ['b', -25.0001], ['c', -25.0], ['d', -25.0]]
```

I wanted the output of method 2, but I can't think why the first method's output produce a `''` around the float number even though I casted it to `float`.

Is is because the float object's casting didn't work permanently?

Comment: `float(v)` isn't casting the underlying object, it's creating a *new* object. That new object *isn't* in the list, which still holds a reference to the old one. You'd have to do e.g. `for index, (k, v) in enumerate(lis): lis[index][1] = float(v)` for that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! I got it now

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for k, v in lis:
    v = float(v)
```

to this:

```
for i in range(n):
    lis[i][1] = float(lis[i][1])
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
for pair in lis:
    pair[1] = float(pair[1])
```

This works because `pair` is a *reference* to the sub-list, so while changing `pair` itself would have no effect, changing an *element* of pair changes the shared sub-list.

Comment: My method is wrong because `v` refers to the newly created object and still the list's reference refers to old string object. Is it the reason?

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara The version you had was setting `k` and `v` to the elements of the list, then changing `v`.  But `v` is just a variable, independent of `lis`, and changing it has no effect on `lis`.

Comment: @NemindaPrabhashwara I updated my answer with an additional way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The float representation in a print statement is without ' but you can add them on both of the sides of the float number by the str() or the repr() methods like

```
lis.append([input(),str(float(input()))])
```

or

```
lis.append([input(),repr(float(input()))])
```

Output

```
[['a', '-25.001'], ['b', '-25.0001'], ['c', '-25.000'], ['d', '-25.0']]
```